# Specify ubuntu repository from which a package is installed?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg from mediubuntu. I've installed the repository per the instructions on:

http://medibuntu.org/repository.php

My conf.d repository listing:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d# less medibuntu.list  
## Please report any bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/medibuntu/
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free #Medibuntu - Ubuntu 10.04 "lucid lynx"
#deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free #Medibuntu (source) - Ubuntu 10.04 "lucid lynx"
```

Yet when I install ffmpeg I still get it installed via the main ubuntu library.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-cache policy ffmpeg
ffmpeg:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1
 Version table:
   4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 0
     500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
```

(Ignore the installed: none; I've installed/purged multiple times trying to get the medibuntu one)

Is there a way I can force it to use the medibuntu repository? Perferably at run-time rather than in a config file.

Comment: If your apt-cache output is correct, it does not appear to be showing ffmpeg as even being present in any other repositories.  Did you run an apt-get update?

Answer (score 2):

As Zoredache mentioned, it's not showing as available from anywhere but main; it needs to be there before this will work.  That said, you'll want to look into using [pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to set the origin used for a given package.

Edit `/etc/apt/preferences`, and add a block something like this:

```
Package: ffmpeg
Pin: origin packages.medibuntu.org
Pin-Priority: 600
```